# A parallelogram problem

Tags: geometry

It might not be hard to do it with a calculator, but without one it is pretty hard
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Pythagorean Theorem, $EB = \sqrt{13^2-5^2} = 12$. Consider the quadrilateral $EDFB$; since $\angle BED = \angle DFB = 90^{\circ}$, we get $\angle EDF + \angle EBF = 180^{\circ} = \angle EDF + \angle BAD$. Thus $\angle BAD = \angle EBF$. From $\triangle AEB$, we get $\cos\angle EBF = \cos\angle BAD = \frac{5}{13}$. Then by the Law of Cosines,
$$EF^2 = EB^2 + BF^2 - 2 EB\cdot BF\cdot\cos\angle EBF 
     = 12^2+13^2 - 2\cdot 156\cdot\frac{5}{13} = 193,$$
so that $EF = \sqrt{193}$. No calculator required.

Comment: +1 same result obtained here, I just wanted to see his attempt (even with using calculator)

Answer (score 2):

Compute $BE$ using Pythagorean Theorem.

Angle chase to get $\angle EBF$.

Apply Law of Cosines to get $EF$.

Comment: What happen if there is no calculator

Comment: Have you tried doing it without a calculator?